Excel formula for dynamic cumulative sum
Below is the excel data, I want to create a formula to get date next to running balance column on which the "RunningBalance" amount is recovered by checking the sum in "CR_AMT" column. E.g. on 6-3-24 running balance was 1796768.77 which was recovered on 15-3-24(1257106+61764+500000 = 1818870 which is greater than running balance amount) so the date 15-3-24 should appear in the cell next to running balance of 17,96,768.77.
The same formula should also be applicable for further running balance amount as well.


Why ignore theDR_AMT? Clearly both columns are related to the balance, why only look at the credit column?

=LET(x_,MAKEARRAY(ROWS(D3:D$22),1,LAMBDA(r_,c_,SUM(D3:INDEX(D3:D$22,r_)))),y_,OFFSET(INDEX(C3:C$22,MATCH(-E3,x_,1)),1,0),IFERROR(y_,""))


(Requires Office 365 compatable version Excel).
Here for sample file.

Note - this will assume your recovery date only tallies credits post the corresponding running balance figure - i.e. after recovering 7k on 27/04  (cell F4), the next recovery date (1/05 in cell F5) is when 7k (still the running bal on 24/04, cell E5) is recovered from 5k (27/04) and 4k (1/05).
